# How type conversions will happen in C++ for following calculation involving 'long long' and 'int' variables

Tags: c++, overflow

I have two variables in my C++ code: long long a and int b. I want to perform the calculation

```
long long a ; 
int b ; 
a = a - b*b
```

I'm unsure about the type conversions that will take place during this operation.

Specifically, I would like to know if the multiplication b*b will be performed while b is still an int, or if b will be automatically converted to a long long before the multiplication takes place.

when i am explicitly converting b to long long i am not getting overflow . but without explicit conversion i am getting overflow.

Comment: `b*b` will be computed as an `int`, since `b` is an `int`.   The resultant `int` will be converted to `long long` and that will be subtracted from `a` to produce the result of `a - b * b`.   The assignment will store the result of that in `a`.    If you are hoping for `b` to be promoted to `long long` before multiplying, or for the multiplication to produce a result of `long long`, you will be disappointed.